# React Functional Component: onClick handler that updates state is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onclick

Below is my react functional component. Every 5 seconds I'm updating the `time` state and showing the time (via `showTime()`).

I also have a button that, when clicked, will push the current time to the `timeList` state (which is an array).

However so far I'm getting a bug in the `handleClick` function. What I want to happen is to push the current time onto the empty `timeList` array (`timeList.push(time)`). So `timeList` would be something like this: ['12:34:57']. However instead `timeList` is `1` when the button is pushed.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(null);
  const [timeList, setTimeList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      calcTime();
    }, [time]
  );

  const calcTime = () => {
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        const today = new Date();
        const timeNow = today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes() + ':' + today.getSeconds();
        setTime(timeNow);
      }, 5000
    );
  };

  const showTime = () => {
    if (time) {
      return <p>{time}</p>
    } else {
      return <p>No time yet</p>
    }
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    if (time) {
      const newTimeList = timeList.push(time);
      console.log(newTimeList); // first time the button is pushed "1" is logged here
      setTimeList(newTimeList);
    }
  };

  const showTimeList = () => {
    if (timeList.length) {
      const timesArr = timeList.map((item) => {
        return <p>item</p>
      });
      return timesArr;
    } else {
      return <p>Time list will go here</p>
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {showTime()}
      {showTimeList()}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add this time to the time list</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please read documentation of [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value)

Comment: `push` return new length of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push` returns new length of array. What you want is to append `time` to `timeList`

```
const handleClick = () => {
    if (time) {
      const newTimeList = [...timeList, time];
      setTimeList(newTimeList);
      // or
      setTimeList(oldTimeList => ([...oldTimeList, time]));
    }
  };
```